# IOException Loading Data into BlazegraphEmbedded

Tags: java, tinkerpop3, blazegraph

I'm having an issue loading my Blazegraph properties file into an embedded instance. When I try to import my *.properties* file into my Java class, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
at blazegraph_tinkerpop_tryout.blazegraph_data_load.loadProperties(blazegraph_data_load.java:55)
at blazegraph_tinkerpop_tryout.blazegraph_data_load.main(blazegraph_data_load.java:32)
```

Call to `loadProperties` function from main:

```
Properties props = loadProperties("sampleprops.properties");
```

My `loadProperties` function (checking to see whether file path is valid, then sending to reader):

```
public static Properties loadProperties(String resource) throws IOException 
{
    Properties p = new Properties();
    Path path = Paths.get(resource);
    Boolean bool = Files.exists(path);
    if (bool)
    {
        System.out.println("File was found. Attempting data load...");
        InputStream is = blazegraph_data_load.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        p.load(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(is)));
        return p;
    }
    System.out.println("The file you entered was not found.");
    return null;
}
```

Here is what my file *sampleprops.properties* looks like:

```
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.bufferMode=DiskRW
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.file=blazegraph.jnl
```

I have been following the setup instructions from the sample Blazegraph app described [here](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/Sesame_API_embedded_mode). If it makes a difference, I am using the Blazegraph/Tinkerpop3 implementation found [here](https://github.com/blazegraph/tinkerpop3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: I switched my `getResourceAsStream` method to a `FileInputStream` method.

The problem was with the placement of my properties file. The `FileInputStream` method seems more forgiving in where you place the file.